# Hibernate value is not deleting from the databse

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

```
@Entity
public class EUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id; 
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<UserRole> roles;
}
```

when doing the following action

```
EUser approveUser = (EUser) userService.getOne(2); 
 approveUser.getRoles().clear();   
 userService.update(approveUser);
 System.out.println(approveUser.getRoles().size());
```

it says the size is zero but when i go the db in the `EUser_UserRole` table i see the value still present. How to solve this??

also in the `EUser_UserRole` it says

```
This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available
```

how can i delete add edit delete manually??

Comment: If that userService.update() is performing an EntityManager.merge(), that should not be necessary. approveUser is most likely going to be a managed entity instance, if you follow CycDemo's suggestion of adding cascading, then making the changes to the entity object should 'automagically' trigger the persistence provider to persist the changes to the database at an opportune moment.

Answer (score 0):

se `CascadeType`. [Reference](http://nsinfra.blogspot.com/2013/03/jpa-20-hibernate-orphanremoval-true.html)

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<UserRole> roles;
```

**Update :**

`orphanRemoval` attribute can use `JPA 2.x` version. You have to find out the deleted `UserRole` data by comparing `old rolesList` and new rolesList`

`orphanRemoval` attribute does not support in `ManyToMany` mapping.

Comment: i am getting the following error >> The attribute orphanRemoval is undefined for the annotation type ManyToMany

Comment: `orphanRemoval ` is support JPA 2.X verson. u cannot use lower verison.

Comment: No version of JPA supports orphanRemoval on ManyToMany

Answer (score 0):

Cascading is indeed a way to let Hibernate do the removal and if I see the posted code, that is most likely what is asked for. But since the question is about *manually* deleting while cascading is more automatic deletion, I have to add the suggestions to:

- use EntityManager.remove()
- invoke a JPQL delete query

Which more fit more the description of "manual" deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a cascade for `ManyToMany` relationships. This can result in an undesired rippling deletion over a wide entity cluster easier than one might hope.

If you want to clear the relationship (delete rows from the join table) for a single user to their roles, you will need to clear the relationship fields on both sides, meaning clearing the List of `UserRole` in `EUser` and removing the current `EUser` from the lists in the respective `UserRole` instances.

EDIT:

You are not deleting any entities from the database when clearing the lists of related entities. The only result will be that some rows in the join table will be deleted and after the next fetch/refresh, your `EUser` and `UserRole` instances will no longer be related.

If you want to remove the UserRoles DB entries, you can do so after removing the relationships to

Comment: i dont want to remove the user. only the roles should be deleted

Comment: Should the roles be removed from the DB or just from the relation? I assumed the second. Please see the edit.